# How to trigger save command in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm running a script that automatically uploads the jupyter notebook that gets run after it is done.

However, I realize that the notebook uploaded is always "time-lagged". It seems that what is displayed in the browser is not in sync with the file on the disk.

How do I trigger a save command from jupyter notebook to what is currently on my browser? I know I can just save from the browser, but this is an automated process. Thanks!

It looks like the following is a viable solution

```
%autosave 1
```

But it errors out "Javascript Error: IPython is not defined", and I can confirm the autosave magic function did not work

I can't find %autosave as one of the options on the official docs too:
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#line-magics

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter by default autosaves every 2 minutes

You can use cell magic to change that

```
%autosave 1
```

to autosave every one second

https://www.webucator.com/blog/2016/03/change-default-autosave-interval-in-ipython-notebook/

Comment: Any performance issues if it's set to %autosave 1?

Or I suppose one could run the magic function, sleep for 1 sec, then run the command to upload the file?

Comment: I can't say I have ever personally used this implementation, so I couldn't tell you about performance degradation. You could set a 1 sec sleep function. That would at least help you with getting the current notebook uploaded without waiting for 2 minutes

Comment: Yes there is a performance issue if your notebook is large

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure whether you are looking to make the browser up-to-date to the new file, or the file up-to-date to changes in the browser.

If you want to make the browser up-to-date to changes in the file, then you can use the [autoreload](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html) extension. You would simply add:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 1
```

To automatically reload your module every second.

On the other hand, if you want to update the file in response to changes you make in the browser, you should use autosave. You would simple add:

```
%autosave 1
```

To save the file every second and thereby update the file on disk.

Comment: I'm trying to make the file up-to-date with the browser. I did the %autosave 1, but it doesn't work: "Javascript Error: IPython is not defined"

Comment: How are you running the Jupyter notebook? I just tried it on a fresh install and mine was working without any additional libraries/extensions. I created a new cell in the notebook and ran that cell -- the output for me was "Autosaving every 1 seconds".

Comment: I found the issue, jupyter-lab does not support %autosave magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save, the hotkey - Ctrl + S save and checkpoint?

Comment: No, it must be done on the command line. No mouse clicks or keyboard presses.